# How do I add a background image to flutter app?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to add a Background image to my Flutter App, and I have gone through all similar questions on SO. The app m runs fine but the image does not appear.

here is my widget code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.list), onPressed: _loadWeb)
        ],
      ),
      body: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: new DecoratedBox(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                image: new DecorationImage(
                  image: new AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: _authList(),
          )
        ],
      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: getFile,
        tooltip: 'Select file',
        child: Icon(Icons.sd_storage),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    ));
  }
```

The app runs fine and the second widget on the stack, which is a listView works normally but the image does not show up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`Scaffold` doesn't support any concept of a background image. What you can do is give the `Scaffold` a transparent color and put it in a `Container` and use the `decoration` property to pull in the required background image. The app bar is also transparent.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("images/logo.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            title: Text('My App'),
            centerTitle: true,
            leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.list,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () {}),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked just fine. I also added color to the container to avoid my image being placed over a black background

Answer (score 13):

Use `BoxDecoration` as the `decoration` attribute of the `Container`:

```
  Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      image: new DecorationImage(
        image: new AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 7):

```
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "MoonLight",
      home: Container(
        decoration:new BoxDecoration(
            image:  new DecorationImage(
              image: new AssetImage("graphics/moon.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,)
        ),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider formatting your response, and add an explanation so viewers can understand what your code does, and how it solves the problem posed in the question.

Comment: Please edit your answer and provide a brief description because StackOverflow puts answers without a brief explanation on the Low Quality posts review queue to see if they should be deleted...  The reason is thousands of people skim answers in a hurry to find the one that best solvers their problem and it wastes the time of a lot of people if they have to spend a lot of time studying answers to figure out if it's really the one they need, and have to read the question, reverse engineer your answer and possibly read language documentation to figure out what your fix solves or how it works.

Answer (score 3):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("asset/images/image.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Use this It will not gonna be having the black color means with transparent background.

Answer (score 1):

**Use `DecoratedBox`:**

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return DecoratedBox(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("your_asset"),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    child: //...,
  );
}
```